# No warning, when passing a member variable by (const) reference to a non-const member function

Tags: c++, constants

I just ran into an error that rises the question:

- Shouldn't I get a compiler warning (MSVC2013) for that, or
- should I learn a new guideline to follow, or
- am I doing something completely stupid?

I'm within a member function and pass a member variable by `const&`-parameter to another member function. The called function is non-`const`.
If I think about that, I'm pretty sure I just shouldn't do that.

The danger is that the `const&` parameters could get magically changed within the called function, when by chance it modifies the originally passed-in member variable. It is allowed to, not being declared `const`.

The example in code:

```
struct S
{
    void caller()
    {
        called_one(this->memvar);
    }

    void called_one(const int& x)
    {
        // ...
        this->memvar = 2; // changes x! That's surprising... at least for this function
        // ...
    }

private:
    int memvar{};
}
```

I think it would be nice to not accidentally run into that error again.
Perhaps it is not the easiest task for the language or compiler to guard against that?
I didn't came across that issue in some popular source of guidelines either yet.

UPDATE:

Perhaps I should clarify, that I don't find the behavior strange. I don't wonder why aliased variables get changed or anything.
It would be nice, if the answers just focused on what function `called_one` finds strange, not myself ;)

UPDATE:

... and `caller` is the one, doing something wrong.
But I think he has a fair chance to realize that (by reading the code). He is passing an alias to something he knows the called function could modify also (not via the parameters passed). And this could lead to unexpected behavior within the called function.

So, if even in this special case it is not possible or reasonable for the compiler to help, I don't see why introducing that pitfall in the form of a guideline isn't worthy or useful.

Comment: You won't be able to modify `x`, but `this->memvar` is not marked as `const`, and neither is the function itself. So the last alternative, you doing something stupid, is what's happening. :)

Comment: _If I think about that, I'm pretty sure I just shouldn't do that_. Well, you can. Your reasoning is wrong. That's all.

Comment: `memvar` is not const, so everything works as excepted. `x` is a `const int&`, so you can't modify `memvar` via `x`.

Comment: @Asu - thanks, the first comment I'm actually understanding. Yes, I can't write to `x`. But I can read it! And within function `called_one` alone - not reasoning beyond, it is just suprising if the value of `x` suddenly changed.

Comment: "I think it would be nice to not accidentally run into that error again" - something tells me now that you have, the likelihood of doing so again has diminished considerably. The phrase would be, "Live and learn."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is equivalent to define

```
f(int& x, const int& y) { x = 2; }
```

and then to call

```
f(x, x);
```

which modifies the second argument `x` without any warning. You just have created an alias between both arguments. So if your call modifies the first argument, it also modifies the second argument.

The compiler has no way to know all alias information between variables. Its job is just to provide a correct code for all possible aliases. As the call respects the signature, the compiler should not deliver any warning.

UPDATE:

There are no guideline at the language level to prevent
such undefined behavior. Aliases are likely to take many
forms. For example, a function can modify a data structure
(tree, list, vector) from its root at the initiative of one
of its element. Then from the root, you can reach the
element and accidentaly modify the element or worse its
support. As you said, it is the programmer's responsibility
to take care about these points.

The compiler could look at the arguments and detect if two arguments are in (trivial) alias with the same type and different const information. But sometimes the programmers want such a behavior without any warning; ex:

```
void mul_assign(double& x, const double& y) { x *= y; }
void sqr_assign(double& x) { mul_assign(x, x); }
```

Comment: Mh, no sorry, I don't find it strange why this is happening. But your words about not being the compilers job and the programmer being forced to keep an overall view over aliasing tend into the right direction.

Comment: Ok, the essence for me is: There are situations where the programmer actually intends to do so. So there shouldn't be a guideline 'Do never...' More something like: 'know what you're doing'.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly legal, just as the simpler

```
int x = 0;
const int &x_r = x;  // x_r can't be changed directly
x = 42;  // also changes (the value referenced by) x_r
```

I would generally consider your code a bad design (but that is hard to tell without context, why you are doing this).

If you want to avoid the alias in your case, just pass `x` by value (at least assuming it is not a bigger struct):

```
void called_one(const int x) // x is guaranteed not to change
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is legal, because you are modifying an `int`, not a `const int&`. A reference can be considered an improved syntaxic sugar for a const pointer. This means your code behaves like this:

```
void called_one(const int *const x) // const pointer to const int
{
    memvar = 2;
}
```

*(NB: `const` applies to the element on the left, unless it's at the beginning - then it applies to the element on the right.)*

`x` is pointing to `memvar`. So when `memvar` is modified, what `x` points is modified. `x` in itself is *not* modified and *cannot* be modified, the same way `*x` cannot be modified because it is `const`. Same goes with references.

But there is no reason `const` would make the original value unmodifiable in itself. It just indicates that you cannot modify `x` only using `x` here.

Also, note that you can decay a `int&` into a `const int&`, which is fine. But you can also cast it back to a `int&` using [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) (if you don't erase `const`s that were in the initial type!! else, that is UB)

```
void called_one(const int& x)
{
    const_cast<int&>(x) = 2; // Legal (and illegal if the `x` passed is actually `const`)
}
```